# what browsers version support GAE Channel Java API

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, channel-api

I want to use GAE Channel Java API with angular

I would like to know which version of the PC browsers, mobile browsers support Channel Java API

[on the official website about this is nothing written](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/)

if you have a working examples angular with Channel API would be grateful

thanks for the help

Comment: find only this
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4780

Comment: Since it's not written explicitly it suppose to work for all.. obviously not the really old ones though :)